# CakePhp Too Many Identical Queries

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a complex Model with many containable. 
However, when I run a query I see in my logs many similar queries:

```
SELECT `Company`.`id` FROM `u`.`companies` AS `Company` LEFT JOIN `u`.`companies` AS `Parent` ON (`Company`.`parent_id` = `Parent`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `u`.`groups` AS `Group` ON (`Company`.`group_id` = `Group`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `Company`.`id` LIMIT 30
SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`name`, `Group`.`alias`, `Group`.`label` FROM ``.`groups` AS `Group` WHERE `Group`.`id` = 1     
SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`name`, `Group`.`alias`, `Group`.`label` FROM `u`.`groups` AS `Group` WHERE `Group`.`id` = 4    
SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`name`, `Group`.`alias`, `Group`.`label` FROM `u`.`groups` AS `Group` WHERE `Group`.`id` = 1       
SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`name`, `Group`.`alias`, `Group`.`label` FROM `u`.`groups` AS `Group` WHERE `Group`.`id` = 1       
SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`name`, `Group`.`alias`, `Group`.`label` FROM `u`.`groups` AS `Group` WHERE `Group`.`id` = 1
```

Why there are so many identical queries?
My query is very simple:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'Company' => array(
      'contain' =>array(     
        'Group',
        'Parent' => array(
            'fields' => array('ragione')
        ),
        'Parent.Group'
    ),
    'limit' => 30,
    'group' => array('Company.id'),
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'order' => array('Company.created ASC')
    )
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that paginate query makes sense? what is Group? Where is Contain?

Comment: Sorry, I mistaken the copy&paste. I edited the post.

Comment: Can you add an example of what that query puts out when you debug the results in the view?